# Jquery TimePicker : How to dynamically change parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

I am using a Jquery Timepicker .

I have two input fields - to Accept times .

```
<input id="startTime"  size="30" type="text" />
<input id="endTime"  size="30" type="text" />
```

I am using a Jquery UI timer as per [documentation](http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/)

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
    'minTime': '6:00am',
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'onSelect': function() {
        //change the 'minTime parameter of #endTime <--- how do I do this ?
     }
});
$('#endTime').timepicker({
    'minTime': '2:00pm',
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'showDuration': true
});
```

I want that when the first timePicker is selected , the 'minTime' parameter for the second gets changed . Basically I am trying to collect the start time and end time for certain activity . And I want that the second input box shows the options from the value of the first input field (start time ) itself .

Comment: I think the same question would be valid for other JQuery elements as well.

Comment: That page has an example (last one) where it does this along with the [source](http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/lib/datepair.js).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would do something like this,

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
                'minTime': '6:00am',
                'maxTime': '11:30pm',
                    'onSelect': function() {

                    $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());                        
              }
            });
```

What you are doing here is that in the `onSelect` function of the `#startTime`, you set the option `minTime` of `#endTime` to the value of `#startTime`

See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXVy2/1/).

Comment: This JS Fiddle shows no change of minTime. It's always 2PM

Answer (score 10):

You can go for onchange event:

```
        $('#startTime').timepicker();

        $('#endTime').timepicker({
            'minTime': '12:00am',
            'showDuration': true
        });

        $('#startTime').on('changeTime', function() {
            $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());
        });
```

I modified the code a bit posted in first reply here is the working fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/NXVy2/215/

You can use on('change'... too

```
    $('#startTime').on('change', function() {
        $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work (anymore?), but this one worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery-UI widgets generally support an `options` method that allows you to change the options on an existing instance. Widget methods are called by supplying a string as the first argument to the plugin call:

```
$(...).widget_name('method_name', arg...)
```

so this should work for you:

```
$('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', new_min_time)
```

Comment: Option works perfectly, This should be marked as a correct answer!