# Setting max time in jQuery Timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

Below is the Current JQuery for My Time Pickers.
If time is picked from `#from` field it set max time of `#to` to selected time.

If I picked 1am from `#from` the max time that can be pick up on `#to` is 1am.

```
var osmaxtime = '20';
$('#from').timepicker({ 'minTime': '9','maxTime': '8','scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
$('#from').on('changeTime', function() {
    var sFrom=$(this).val();
    $('#to').timepicker({ 'minTime': '9','maxTime':sFrom,'scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
});
$('#to').timepicker({ 'minTime': '9','maxTime': osmaxtime,'scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
```

Now I want to increase the max time for `#to` Field according to `#from` field.

e.g., if I pick up 1am from `#from` the max time for `#to` is 4am (+4 Hours)

```
$('#from').on('changeTime', function() {
        var sFrom=$(this).val();
        var sFromPuls=sFrom+4;// Here is the problem because the value of sFrom is in String or something else.
        $('#to').timepicker({ 'minTime': '9','maxTime':sFrom,'scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958387/jquery-timepicker-how-to-dynamically-change-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was solved by following code -

```
$('#from').timepicker({ 'minTime': 8,'maxTime': 20,'scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
    $('#from').on('change', function() {
        var fromTime=$(this).val();
        var hrs = Number(fromTime.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        var format = fromTime.match(/00(.*)$/)[1];
        if (format == "pm" && hrs < 12) hrs = hrs + 12;
        if (format == "am" && hrs == 12) hrs = hrs - 12;
        var hours = (hrs+4).toString();         
        var sFromPuls= (parseInt(osSeletecdTime)+4).toString();
        $('#to').timepicker({ 'minTime': fromTime,'maxTime':hours ,'scrollDefaultNow': true,'step': 60 });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround the var with Number to make jQuery recognize it as number to add 4 to it

```
$('#from').on('changeTime', function() {
  var sFrom=$(this).val();
  var sFromPuls=Number(sFrom)+4; // Surround with Number()
  $('#to').timepicker({ 'minTime': '9',
  'maxTime':sFromPuls, //write correct var name 
  'scrollDefaultNow': true,
  'step': 60 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [onSelect documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) and use it on your timepicker

```
$('#example').datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
              //Here you can add 4 hours to the start time
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but this is what I already have. I believe it is same with below line in my code.

`$('#from').on('changeTime', function() {
});
`