# How to limit hour in Date Range Picker JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I am using Date Range Picker JQuery plugin and i can't limit the hour. I want to user can select 8 AM to 5 PM.

My Code:

```
$('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    "locale": {
        "format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm",
        "applyLabel": "Onayla",
        "cancelLabel": "İptal",
        "weekLabel": "H",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Pa",
            "Pt",
            "Sa",
            "Ça",
            "Pe",
            "Cu",
            "Ct"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Ocak",
            "Şubat",
            "Mart",
            "Nisan",
            "Mayıs",
            "Haziran",
            "Temmuz",
            "Ağustos",
            "Eylül",
            "Ekim",
            "Kasım",
            "Aralık"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    minDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1,'day'),
    maxDate: moment().startOf('month').add(6,'month'),
    startDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1,'day'),
    MinTime: moment().hour(0).add(8)
});
```

I solve this problem with this code:

```
$('input[name="date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    if(picker.startDate.hour() > 17 || picker.startDate.hour() < 8){
        $('input[name="date"]').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(picker.startDate.hour(0).add(8,'hour'));
        //ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But i don't want to show them 0 to 24 hours. Just 8 to 17.

Edit: I used that code but didn't change anything.

```
hourMin: 8,
hourMax: 16,
```

Comment: Hi, how are you initializing the input with daterangepicker plugin?

Comment: I am added my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032640/setting-max-time-in-jquery-timepicker

Comment: No, it's for TimePicker not for the date range picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the library does not allow natively what you want to achieve. It would be nice to have `minHour` and `maxHour` (as you suggest).

What you can do to trick the user is to hide with CSS the hours you do not want him to choose:

```
// This will hide the first 8 items so that 8 hours is the first option shown.
.hourselect option:nth-child(-n+8) {
    display: none;
}
// This will hide the hours from 18 onwards.
.hourselect option:nth-child(n+19) {
    display: none;
}
```

With this you are hiding the unwanted hours. The problem is the first time you open the range picker you see 0 as the selected hour. To correct this you can set your `startDate` so that it starts from 8:

```
startDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1,'day').add(8, 'hours'),
```

Another solution based on JavaScript is to remove the undesired hours when the user opens the range picker:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var $hours = picker.container.find('.hourselect').children();

    $hours.filter(':gt(17)').remove();    
    $hours.filter(':lt(8)').remove();
});
```