# How to redefine timepicker input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I am making a form for scheduling. 
It has date and time. If someone picks Saturday, available hours are from 8:30 to 12:00. Monday- Friday: 8:30 to 15:30.

I have this:

```
    var datum = "";
    jQuery("#meeting_date").change(function(){
    $("#meeting_time").html("");
   datum = $(this).val().split("-");
   day_of_the_week =new Date(datum[2], datum[1]-1, datum[0]).getDay(); 

   if(day_of_the_week==6) {
        $("#meeting_time").timepicker({
            timeFormat: ("H:mm"),
            minTime: "8:30",
            maxTime: "12:00"
        });
   }
   else {
        $("#meeting_time").timepicker({
            timeFormat: ("H:mm"),
            minTime: "8:30",
            maxTime: "15:00"
        });
   }

  });
```

It works fine on the first date change. On the ones that follow, the timepicker doesn't change. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found the solution, thanks to @mu is too short and his answer to this question [Jquery TimePicker : How to dynamically change parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958387/jquery-timepicker-how-to-dynamically-change-parameters).

I needed to use OPTIONS to readjust the MAX DATE:

```
    var datum = "";
    jQuery("#meeting_date").change(function(){
    $("#meeting_time").html("");
   datum = $(this).val().split("-");
   day_of_the_week =new Date(datum[2], datum[1]-1, datum[0]).getDay(); 

   if(day_of_the_week==6) {
        $("#termin_sastanka").timepicker('option', 'maxTime', "12:00");
   }
   else {
        $("#termin_sastanka").timepicker('option', 'maxTime', "15:00");
   }

  });
```