# .val() of fields not updating

Tags: jquery, function, dom

I'm stumped on why my two variable below are not updating after the first time a value is selected:

```
function setPrimeLimits() {
    var selectedStart = $('#space_global_start').val();
    var selectedEnd = $('#space_global_end').val();
    $('#prime_global_start, #prime_global_end').timepicker({
        minTime: selectedStart,
        maxTime: selectedEnd,
    });
}

$('#space_global_start, #space_global_end').on('changeTime', setPrimeLimits);
```

`selectedStart` and `selectedEnd` are both timepickers and the first time they are selected, the function works fine to limit two other timepickers (`#prime_global_start` and `#prime_global_end`) but on the 2nd and subsequent update of the field (they are dropdowns) the variables no longer update.

Usually, I would try event delegation, but it seems like I'm already doing that, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

This is all wrapped in a document.ready function.

HTML code:

**Timepicker fields that I'm getting the vars from:**

```
<input type="text" name="space_global_start" id="space_global_start" class="spaceTimePickerStart" value="<?php echo (null !== get_space_meta( 'space_global_start' )) ? get_space_meta( 'space_global_start' ) : '' ?>" />
<input type="text" name="space_global_end" id="space_global_end" class="spaceTimePickerEnd" value="<?php echo (null !== get_space_meta( 'space_global_end' )) ? get_space_meta( 'space_global_end' ) : '' ?>"/>
```

**Timepicker fields that I'm trying to limit:**

```
<input type="text" name="prime_global_start" id="prime_global_start" class="primeTimePickerStart" value="<?php echo (null !== get_space_meta( 'prime_global_start' )) ? get_space_meta( 'prime_global_start' ) : '' ?>" />
<input type="text" name="prime_global_end" id="prime_global_end" class="primeTimePickerEnd" value="<?php echo (null !== get_space_meta( 'prime_global_end' )) ? get_space_meta( 'prime_global_end' ) : '' ?>"/>
```

Comment: can you update your html code too

Comment: Sure, one sec. I've got to simplify it real quick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('#prime_global_start, #prime_global_end').timepicker({
    minTime: selectedStart,
    maxTime: selectedEnd,
});
```

Do this:

```
$('#prime_global_start').timepicker('option', 'minTime', selectedStart);
$('#prime_global_end').timepicker('option', 'maxTime', selectedEnd);
```

See this question for further explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958470/1224539

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you, that did the trick. I'll accept your answer momentarily.